# Send an array from a parent component to a child component in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to play a sound in a child component of your Vue.js app, but without navigating to the child component's URL. I believe that sending props from the parent component to the child component would be the best solution. However, I am still unable to send an array of sounds that I want the child component to play from the parent component. I am not sure what is causing the issue.

```html
// Parent Code

<div>
  <playsound :sounds="sounds" />
  </div>  
</template>  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import playsound from './test3.vue'
   
  const sounds = ref(['https://koh-abx,com/sound/9.mp3', 'https://koh-abx,com/sound/2.mp3']); 

  const collection1Data = ref([]);
```

```javascript
//child code 
const props = defineProps({
  sounds: {
  type: Array,
  required: true
}
})
const audioRef = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  const sounds = [
    'https://koh-abx.com/sound/invite.mp3',
    'https://koh-abx.com/sound/B.mp3',
  ]
 
let currentSound = 0
    audioRef.value = new Audio(sounds[currentSound])
    audioRef.value.addEventListener("ended", () => {
      currentSound++
      if (currentSound < sounds.length) {
        audioRef.value.src = sounds[currentSound]
        audioRef.value.play()
      }
    })
  
    audioRef.value.play()
  })
```

I expect I can change name of file in parent then child component play sound

Comment: You are defining `props` which should contain the `sounds` array, but then not using it anywhere in the code...

Comment: when I change audioRef.value = new Audio(sounds[currentSound]) to audioRef.value = new Audio(prop.sounds[currentSound]) the parent code have problems

Comment: when I change from audioRef.value.src = sounds[currentSound] to audioRef.value.src = props.sounds[currentSound]  it mix between pasent and child

Comment: Ichange to const sounds = props.sounds  and it work Thank you very much Hovercraft Full Of Eels